# Delete Even Number of Nodes in Linked List And Print in Reverse

Tags: java, list, reverse

What should be the logic followed for this scenario.

I have a linear linked list. I want to print the list in reverse order starting from the second last node.. but while removing even number of nodes. 
For example: 
 34(Node 1- Odd), 65(Node 2 - even), 733(Node 3 - odd), 34(Node 4 - even),
56(Node 5 - odd), 33(Node 6 - even)..

Now, I want output like this..
56 (Second last node), 733(Node 4 is removed being even and it is printed cz it is odd), 34(Again even removed, odd printed in reverse form) .. and so on.

Please tell me if I have not cleared my question. And help me with the logic. 
Thanks

**Updated**

```
// Task A
public class LinkedList {

    protected class NodeReference {
        int info;
        NodeReference next;
        public NodeReference pLoc;
    }

    NodeReference headRef,pLoc, Loc; 
    int totalElements;
    private NodeReference next; 

    public LinkedList() {
        totalElements = 0;
        headRef = null;
    }

    public void insertAtFront(int value) {
        NodeReference newNode = new NodeReference();
                newNode.info = value;
                newNode.next = headRef;
                headRef = newNode;
    }
// Task B
    public void printList(){
        NodeReference location = headRef;
        if(headRef!=null) {
             System.out.println("The list is being printed...."); 
             while(location != null) {
             System.out.println(location.info);
             location = location.next; 
             }

        } // if block ends
        else
            System.out.println("Sorry, List is Empty!");
    }   
// Task C
    public NodeReference reverseList(NodeReference headRef) {
        if(headRef==null || headRef.next == null) 
            return headRef;

        NodeReference pLoc1 = headRef;
        NodeReference pLoc2 = headRef.next;

        headRef.next = null;
        while(pLoc1!= null || pLoc2!= null){
            NodeReference tempRef = pLoc2.next;
            pLoc2.next = pLoc1;
            pLoc1 = pLoc2;
            if (tempRef != null){
                pLoc2 = tempRef;
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }

        return pLoc2;
    }
    public void reverse() {
        reverseList(headRef);
    }
// Task D 
    public void deleteEven() {
        Loc = headRef; pLoc = null;
        while (Loc != null) {
            Loc = (Loc.next).next;
            System.out.println(Loc.info); 

        }
    }
}
```

Driver Program

```
public class LinkedListDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
        l.insertAtFront(4); l.insertAtFront(7); 
        l.insertAtFront(3); l.insertAtFront(2);
        l.insertAtFront(8); l.insertAtFront(4);
        l.insertAtFront(6);
        l.printList(); 
        System.out.println("Printing Just Odd Values While Deleting Evens");
        try { 
            l.deleteEven();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" End of the List..");

        }



    }

}
```

Comment: You can use `LinkedList#descendingIterator` then iterate on the list with this iterator and skip one element every two elements. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#descendingIterator--

Comment: I know this .. but I am not stuck in implementing it exactly into program..

Comment: It would not be responsible for me to give some ready-to-copy-paste code. please show what you have tried.

Comment: Alright. See my code.

Comment: Are you required to implement your own `LinkedList` or does the teacher allow you to use the existing `java.util.LinkedList` class?

Comment: Yes, my own implementation is required throughout the semester.

Answer (score 1):

The `deleteEven` method was almost good but you actually skip the first element.

Also, you declare those attributes that are used only in `deleteEven` method and should therefore be local variables, not class attributes :

```
NodeReference headRef // Useless -> ,pLoc, Loc;
```

I have re-written deleteEven like this :

```
public void deleteEven() {
  NodeReference loc = headRef;
  while(loc != null && loc.next != null) {
    loc.next = loc.next.next;
    loc = loc.next;
  }
}
```

And also changed the main method a bit :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
    l.insertAtFront(4);
    l.insertAtFront(7);
    l.insertAtFront(3);
    l.insertAtFront(2);
    l.insertAtFront(8);
    l.insertAtFront(4);
    l.insertAtFront(6);
    l.printList(); 
    System.out.println("Deleting Evens");
    l.deleteEven();
    l.printList();
}
```

Output :

```
The list is being printed....
6
4
8
2
3
7
4
Deleting Evens
The list is being printed....
6
8
3
4
```

Now, you have to implement the `reverseList` method.

**Hint** : the list can be double-linked (each node keeps a reference to the previous and next node). It will then be easier to keep a reference to the last element of the list and iterate from it.